# Next Quarter Start and End Date SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I know how to calcualte the current quarter start and end date. I even have the calcualtion for the Next Quarter Start date. However, the next quarter end date does not seem to be working for me. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("q", DateDiff("q", ("1/1/1900"+2), Today), DateSerial(1900,1,1)))
```

Comment: You should ask a different question instead of editing a question *with an accepted answer* and asking something completely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, you need to add 2 to the first quarter calculation instead of to the date itself.  So the expression should be:

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("q", DateDiff("q", ("1/1/1900"), Today)+2, DateSerial(1900,1,1)))
```